# Does 2 Tim.1:16-18 imply that Onesiphorus is already dead?

Tags: 2-timothy

Does the Greek text of 2 Tim. 1:16-18 imply that Onesiphorus had already been dead by the time of writing these words?:

> The Lord give mercy unto the house of Onesiphorus; for he oft
>   refreshed me, and was not ashamed of my chain:  But, when he was in
>   Rome, he sought me out very diligently, and found me. The Lord grant
>   unto him that he may find mercy of the Lord in that day: and in how
>   many things he ministered unto me at Ephesus, thou knowest very well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key of this text is the phrase **that day**, which occurs in the following three verses:

> [**2 Tim 1:16-18**](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Timothy%201%3A12&version=NASB;SBLGNT) (NASB)
>   <sup>16</sup> The Lord grant mercy to the house of Onesiphorus, for he often refreshed me and was not ashamed of my chains; <sup>17</sup> but when he was in Rome, he eagerly searched for me and found me— <sup>18</sup>the Lord grant to him to find mercy from the Lord on **that day**—and you know very well what services he rendered at Ephesus.
>
> [**2 Tim 4:8**](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Timothy%204%3A8&version=NASB;SBLGNT) (NASB)
>   <sup>8</sup> in the future there is laid up for me the crown of righteousness, which the Lord, the righteous Judge, will award to me on **that day**; and not only to me, but also to all who have loved His appearing.
>
> [**2 Tim 1:12**](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Timothy%201%3A12&version=NASB;SBLGNT) (NASB)
>   <sup>12</sup> For this reason I also suffer these things, but I am not ashamed; for I know whom I have believed and I am convinced that He is able to guard what I have entrusted to Him until **that day**.

If the author of the epistle refers to himself as receiving his reward of due compensation on **that day**, and the author was alive when he wrote these words, then why should we assume that Onesiphorus was necessarily already dead just because he too was supposed to receive his reward of due compensation on **that day**?

Answer (score 4):

I think that we need to understand firstly that Paul is contrasting Onesiphorus and his household with those people he mentions in v14. He is commending them for their care of him.

The fact that it is just Onesiphorus' household that Paul speaks of in v15 and not Onesiphorus himself suggests that he wasn't there at the time. That might mean that he was dead, or it could simply mean he was elsewhere, after all Paul refers to the household of Stephanas in 1 Cor 16:15 when he is very much alive (just not at home 1 Cor 16:17)

It is easy to read a lot into the term "The Lord grant mercy to" in v15 and conclude that Paul was praying for comfort for the household. But that is not what he says. Notice in v18 he also prays for mercy for Onesiphorus as well and it doesn't seem to me that praying for mercy for one already dead would fit with Paul's theology. Paul is always praying/ asking for mercy or grace for people. Many of his letters open with such a prayer: Rom 1:7, 1 Cor 1:3, 2 Cor 1:2, Gal 1:3, Eph 1:2, Phil 1:2, Col 1:2, 1 Thess 1:1, 2 Thess 1:2, 1 Tim 1:2, 2 Tim 1:2, Tit 1:4, Phm 1:3

In the end the evidence is not conclusive either way, so it seems clear that Paul presumed Timothy would know the situation, and that beyond our own curiosity the question does not have a great significance. By that I mean that we should not build a doctrine upon this as a key text, or even use it as a proof text for 'prayer for the dead' etc. The ambiguity precludes it's worth to that end.

Comment: "it doesn't seem to me that praying for mercy for one already dead would fit with Paul's theology." Begging the question. Nice try though. :)

Comment: Not really but if you require me to enlarge upon that point I will.

Comment: In Phil 1:23 Paul taught that upon death the believer enters immediately into God's presence. In 2 Cor 5:1-8 he speaks of 3 states of existence, this one we experience now, and intermediary state (without flesh) and a final (eternal) state. Nowhere else in his words do we read of him actually teaching people to pray for the dead (except this passage that is ambiguous at best). It seems to me to draw that conclusion from this text is to set Paul against Paul and as a conservative Christian I cannot do that

Comment: Thanks for your answer. "By that I mean that we should build a doctrine upon this as a key text" - Did you mean to say "we should NOT" instead?

Comment: Yes I did. My mind works faster then my fingers sometimes

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It is convincing enough to belief that it is not expected for prayers to be made for the dead. But during condolence visit to bereaved families, one just find himself praying prayers such as: may his/her soul rest in perfect peace.

Answer (score 1):

The text provided in the question is an accurate translation of the [Greek text seen here](http://www.scripture4all.org/OnlineInterlinear/NTpdf/2ti1.pdf). This does not state that Onesiphorus is already dead, but gives us clues that lead to that conclusion. First, the mention of Onesiphorus' grieving family ("The Lord give mercy unto the house of Onesiphorus"), then the hope that the Lord will grant mercy in that (Judgement) day. [2 Timothy 4:19](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG0839/__P119.HTM) says: "Greet Prisca and Aquila 9 and the family of Onesiphorus," once again implying that Onesiphorus is dead, or at least absent.

We can pause from looking at the actual words of the passage, to look at the context in which Second Timothy was written. Although traditionally attributed to Saint Paul, [most modern critical scholars argue that 2 Timothy was written after Paul's death](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Epistle_to_Timothy#Authorship). Paul never mentioned Onesiphorus in his undisputed epistles, so it is likely that Onesiphorus was a literary construct invented by the actual author of *2 Timothy*.

Returning to the meaning of Greek words in this passage, the name Onesiphorus  means ‘bringing advantage’. When we consider that Onesiphorus is singled out as someone not ashamed of Paul’s imprisonment and was the one person who sought out Paul in Rome, when others had abandoned him, then he truly did bring advantage. Although Greeks were sometimes given aspirational names, the appropriateness of Onesiphorus in this case is further evidence that he was a literary construct and existed only within Second Timothy. Onesiphorus was not dead if he never lived.

Comment: ".. so it is likely that Onesiphorus was a literary construct invented by the actual author of 2 Timothy" - So you are saying here that the name Onesiphorus here is not actually a name that would be a reference to one particular person, but rather some phrase with the meaning of "bringing advantage", right? If so, then how should this verse be translated then? Something like "The Lord give mercy unto the house of **the one who was to my advantage;** for he oft refreshed me, and was not ashamed of my chain" or something? Will this rendition not be quite a stretch and rather awkward looking?

Comment: @brilliant A parallel is Luke/Acts which were addressed to Theophilus, generally accepted as a real person although his name means "Lover of God." But it *could* be that the author meant it symbolically. Onesimus was a common name for slaves, meaning ‘useful’, but is also phonetically similar to Onesiphorus. We know that Onesimus really lived, because *Philemon* is an undisputed Pauline epistle. I am saying that when the anonymous author of 2 Tim was looking around for a name, he chose a name appropriate for the situation and was perhaps inspired by Onesimus, who also helped Paul in prison.

Comment: To make a point that is outside the scope of the question, and which I therefore did not include in my answer, the 'Pastorals' (1 & 2 Tim, Titus) were written so long after the time of Paul that everyone he knew was already dead when they were written.

Comment: 1) "I am saying that when the anonymous author of 2 Tim was looking around for a name, he chose a name appropriate for the situation and was perhaps inspired by Onesimus, who also helped Paul in prison." - I am sorry for being such a dummy, but I still don't get it. I know that some names have meaning, for example, the name "Carpus" in 2 Tim. 4:13 means "fruit", but I am a bit puzzled by the apparent contradiction in your words. On one hand, you say "the anonymous author of 2 Tim was looking around for a name, he chose a name appropriate for the situation", which I take as your agreeing that ↙

Comment: 2) the person Onesiphorus did really exist, except he might've gone by some other name, that is, not by name "Onesiphorus" that the author chose; but, on the other hand, in your answer you said "Onesiphorus in this case is further evidence that he was a literary construct and existed only within Second Timothy. Onesiphorus was not dead if he never lived." So, what's your point here about that person's existence? If this is the case of "a literary construct", did the person still exist regardless of what name he really had?

Comment: @brilliant No, you are not a dummy: this is quite difficuly and I am happy to work through it with you. When we have been brought up to believe that Paul wrote 2 Timothy, it is a mental stretch to think of someone else using Paul's name, after his death, to add credibility to his own message.

Comment: 2 Timothy was not written by Paul and was not written to Timothy. It was written as well-intentioned pastoral advice to the churches as they existed decades after Paul's death. The scholarly position is that the author tried to copy Paul's style so that he could plausibly attribute his letter (actually an encyclical) to Paul, and so used characters known to Paul whenever possible, but of course in new situations. *Onesimus* (Useful) really lived, because Philemon is an undisputed Pauline epistle. But Onesiphorus did not - he was a literary construct - a fictitious character.

Comment: That is one scholarly opinion, but there are others which do accredit Paul with this letter and date it around AD67. Bear in mind that the early church seems to have accepted it as authentic, for example Polycarp (c. 69-155) quotes what we now know as 1 Tim 2:12 in his Letter to the Philippians

Comment: Twentieth-century scholars adhering to Pauline authorship or Pauline origin of the Pastorals include W. Lock (1924), O. Roller (1933), D. Guthrie (1957), J. N. D. Kelly (1963), J. Jeremias (1963), C. F. D. Moule (1965), C. Spicq (1969), B. Reicke (1976), W. Metzger (1976), and D. E. Hiebert (1978).

Answer (score 0):

Onesiphorus, I believe, was not dead because Paul would not have prayed for him. Besides those who die in Christ need no one to pray for them, as they are "in Christ". That's a guarantee.

> And the LORD, he *it is* that doth go before thee; he will be with thee, he will not fail thee, neither forsake thee: fear not, neither be dismayed.
>   -- Deuteronomy 31:8 (KJV)

I believe wholeheartedly that those who pray for the dead are wasting their time and know not the Lord in truth. Let's use our time praying for the living and not the dead. Much more profitable!

Comment: Welcome to BH.SE! Please [take the tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a feel for how the site functions.

Answer (score 0):

According to the current official teaching of the RCC, purgatory is not a place to PAY for one's venial sins, but a place of purification to prepare the deceased 'Christian' to live in heaven.  Thus, purgatory implies that the person enduring it already has full pardon or mercy in Jesus.  The person's sins are redeemed by Jesus' death on the cross.  The person in purgatory is said to already be forgiven.  The person is assured heaven in the official view and so we cannot conclude that 2 Timothy 1:16-18 is proof of purgatory.  So is it then proof of hell then?  We cannot conclude that either for the fact that mercy is assured to the one who has met the conditions of divine pardon in this life.  If Onesimus was dead and Paul was praying for mercy, then it would imply Paul was praying that Onesimus would be able to avoid hell.  And such an interpretation would also be speculation.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question misses the point. It seems logical that Paul prays for mercy for Onesiphorus not because he was already dead, but because he too had turned away and abandoned Paul like the others. Rather Paul, not wanting O. to fall under God's judgment for this act, prays that God will have mercy on him and remember his many kindnesses on Paul's behalf.

Comment: Can you disproof the opposite possibility?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Dave Cragoe Hi Dave, welcome to BH-Stack Exchange, we are glad you are here. Please be sure to take the [site tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) and read our [code of conduct](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/conduct). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Paul is asking for God's mercy on Onesiphorus's family.  And he is speaking of O in the past tense.  It is obvious, in context, that O. is dead.

All of the times Paul uses the phrase "on that day" (someone receiving God's grace or some sort of reward") Paul means **eternal life**!

From all times and all places, for 1500 years and continuing all 2000+ years (excepting for the relatively small faction of the continuing-to-fracture-Protestant movement,) every Christian believed that that term meant being received into heaven, the ultimate reward.

Only when the Protestant movement started teaching that all truth must be found only in the pages of the Bible, did this term begin to mean some sort of reward given to us once we died and immediately went to heaven (because of a prayer we once said, not based on the state of our soul's charity with God and man at the time of their death.  Notice I did not say based on all their "works" piled up.)

They dismissed 1500 years of Catholic belief in many truths given by Jesus orally to the Apostles (the faith once delivered to the saints.)  Which continues to this day in the Magisterium (where we can look to for **authority**.  Where do Protestants get their authority?)

The Bible itself (which is where Protestants claim all truth comes from) was given to all Christians by The Church that Jesus instituted on earth: The Catholic Church.  It was never spoken about by Jesus at all.  He commissioned his Apostles to go and **tell** everything Jesus had **told** them.  He never said to "write this all down."

Why can you believe that the men who decided which books were in the canon (around 400 A.D.,) but do not believe what they themselves lived and believed?  And changed the world with their lives and beliefs.

And **they** believed that Paul was asking for God's mercy on the soul of a dear, dead friend (No one can know for sure if someone is in Heaven, Hell, or Purgatory, so we ask for God's mercy on their soul in any case.)

The **huge** problem with the idea that Paul is only speaking of a reward (not eternal life) as something we will receive because of something we did above and beyond what is necessary, and **not** the reward of Heaven because we "fought the good fight" and "ran the race set before us" and persevered to the end, is that it makes living a **moral life** in **charity with god and neighbor... optional**!

If I can go to heaven and be with God forever and never have to change my behavior, with God's grace, through Jesus Christ, consistently changing the way I **act**, after my passions react to a situation, which takes **a lot** of thought, prayer and **change**.

**Why would I bother?**

God will always just forgive me, and actually, already has!  I say "the believer's prayer" and all my sins are forgiven past, present, and future.  Why do we wonder that Christians have a bad rep for being hypocrites?  They never have to do a thing to change and their salvation is guaranteed!
**Plus**, praying for those who have gone on before us gives us the sense of community that God created us for.  Not with those just living around us now, but "the great cloud of witnesses" who have lived on this earth before us and are now in Heaven (or purgatory) praying for us as well.
And saying that Paul is asking for God's grace on O. because he has fallen away, is not supported in the text at all.  Nowhere does it say that O. fell away.

**Conclusion**: The Authority of The Church tells us that O. is dead and Paul is praying for a man no longer living on this earth, but alive in Heaven/Purgatory.